# How can I use dependency injection without changing/adding constructors

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have the following asp.net c# code

```
{      
    public class Test
    {

    ISomeService _someService;

    public Test()
    {
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
    _someService.Do();
    }
}
```

I need to provide ISomeService to Test class, and I dont know how to do it. I am not allowed to add additional construction which would make entire problem go away, for example

```
public Test(ISomeService someService)
{
    _someService = someService;
}
```

I tried using setter injection or method injection but that didnt do the trick.

Implementation of ISomeService in SomeService class also uses constructor injection, such as

```
public SomeService(IService1 service1, Iservice2 service2)
```

Not sure what to do here.

**HERE IS A COMPLETE CODE**

```
 public class Startup
    {
        private IService _service;

        public Startup()
        {

        }

        public Startup(IService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }


        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

            var container = new UnityContainer();            
            container.RegisterType<IService, Service>();
            config.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);

            app.UseWebApi(config);

            _service.DoSomething());

        }
    }
```

_service is null

Comment: Why can't you add parameters to your Constructor?

Comment: @MindSwipe it is an owin  startup class

Comment: Which dependency injection framework do you use?

Comment: If it's the owin startup class, then you can't even use DI, as your container isn't producing it. Unless owin itself has methodology for DI.

Comment: Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19781970/9363973)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781970/how-to-use-di-container-when-owinstartup see here

Comment: @Magnus I am using unity

Comment: I have seen that question, since it is from 2013 i thought there is a more elegant solution

Comment: You still have to set up and register your container before the startup class gets created by owin.

Comment: I am confused since everything is regstered in UnityConfig.RegisterComponents all before it hits startup.cs file

Comment: It would be helpful to explain why you can't add a new constructor. Also Why didn't property and method injection "not do the trick"?

Comment: @StormMuller well additional constructor in startup.cs doesnt do a thing

Comment: @mko This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The question in its current state is also incomplete and therefore unclear. Read [ask] and then edit the question to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem, allowing a better understanding of what is being asked.

Comment: What part of my question is unclear to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is this

```
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

serviceCollection.AddTransient<IService, Service>();

// create service provider
var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

_service = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<Service>(serviceProvider);

_service.DoSomething();
```

Thanks to this answer [Dependency Injection with classes other than a Controller class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37189984/dependency-injection-with-classes-other-than-a-controller-class)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a factory to create your object. That would have an instance of ISomeService injected on the constructor.

Then in a CreateTest() method on your factory set the ISomeService property directly.

```cs
public class Factory
{
    private readonly ISomeService someService;

    public Factory(ISomeService someService)
    {
        this.someService = someService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(someService));
    }
    public TestClass CreateTestClass()
    {
        var instance = new TestClass();
        instance.SomeService = this.someService;
        return instance;
    }

}
```

You should note that most DI providers have built in functionality to allow factory semantics without the need to create your own factories.