# Is OWIN a Dependency injection container or DI framework?

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, owin, .net-framework-version, dependency-inversion

We have an ASP.NET 4.8 project and we thought to introduce Dependency injection principle. A colleague suggested to use OWIN as DI container.

I tried to search for more information regarding ownin, but I don't seem to get the relation between owin and dependency injection.

Can OWIN be used as dependency injection container like some other frameworks: Autofac, Ninject, etc?

Comment: What DI framework will you use? Typically would any DI-framework have its own middleware.

Comment: I don't think so. OWIN stands for Open Web Interface for .NET. He might be suggesting to use a DI container like Unity or Ninject to configure OWIN startup. [This might be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781970/how-to-use-di-container-when-owinstartup)

Comment: thank you Manik for your reply. Actually I proposed Ninject or autofac, but he said no, use owin. I have not used owin, and that put me off the track. He was sure we can use owin as DI container. But I had never come across any tutorials or blocks, etc that used owin as DI container/framework to create loosely coupled components. So, this tells me that he had no idea at all about DI or had never heard about unity, ninject, autofac, etc

Comment: OWIN is not a DI framework, so your colleague misunderstood the concepts.